# Nodejs microservices sometimes displays 502 bad gateway error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, microservices, api-gateway

I have a list of microservices running in nodejs (version 14.8.1)and mongodb connected through mongoose, which is accessed through a express api gateway. At times I get a 502 gateway issue , The same gets resolved in the subsequent hits. Any guidance on how to handle this will be a good start.

Comment: Check the API gateway logfiles…

Comment: @robertklep - If i see the express api gateway logs i see the below error      
28|express | 2022-08-29T18:42:20.668Z [EG:policy] warn: socket hang up
28|express | 2022-08-29T22:38:41.327Z [EG:policy] warn: socket hang up
28|express | 2022-08-29T22:45:47.176Z [EG:policy] warn: socket hang up
28|express | 2022-08-30T00:00:24.441Z [EG:policy] warn: socket hang up

Comment: Any idea as is this a issue in the gateway or the server its trying to connect?

Comment: Looks like an issue with the server the gateway is trying to connect to, like it's crashing.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for the comment . It looks like my aws-iot-device-sdk thingshadows is throwing econnreset sometimes. I need to handling this to avoid that issue. Thanks for the guidance